# Conflicting requirements: table columns expand to fill the space available, but also truncate the text

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table that has 4 "fixed" columns, and 1 to 4 variable width columns.  For the purposes of brevity, call these variable width columns "attributes" - let me re-iterate, I don't know until run time (actually, until I make an AJAX call) how many there are. I had no problem making all this work with `<table>` and setting "width" on the fixed columns and "min-width" on the variable ones.  If there was more text than would fit in the variable width columns, the text wrapped just fine.  But now my boss is throwing a curve ball at me.  He wants it so (some of the time) instead of wrapping, it truncates the text. I tried adding the following to the class for the `<td>` for the attribute columns:

```
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
```

and that didn't do anything.  So I wrapped the text in the attribute columns in a `<div>` and set those CSS parameters on the div instead of the tr, but what happens now is that the columns become big enough to hold the entire text, instead of truncating it, so I end up with a table that's thousands of pixels wide with a huge horizontal scroll bar.  That's not what I want at all.  I can set a fixed width on the div which makes the text truncate, but then I don't get it resizing depending on how many columns there are. I tried setting a `width: 20%` on the div, but then I get a column that's huge, but with a div that only takes 20% of it - and of course a horizontal scroll bar.

Is there any way I can get the resizing I want or will I be forced to make some calculation at load time and set "width" accordingly?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CSUyT/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1):

You need to constrain the width of the same element you're applying `text-overflow` to in order for it to work correctly.

Comment: I already had `width="100%"` on the table.  I tried changing that to `width="940"` and it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle we could look at and tinker with?

Comment: You're using `text-overflow` without specifying `max-width`. You have to constrain the size on the same element that you're applying `text-overflow` to. In your case it seems like the `div`s are entirely unnecessary; you should be able to style the `td`s directly with `max-width` and `text-overflow`.

Comment: As I said in the question, I'm trying to get things to resize to fit the available space, when I don't know how much space I have until it's loaded.  If I set a max-width, the table would be a different width depending how many attribute columns I have, but my goal is to use the whole width of the screen regardless of how many columns I have.

Comment: Then you can set the `max-width` in percent, which will be relative to the table itself. If you're not sure how many attribute columns you'll have, you may have to dynamically set `max-width` based on the number of columns, either when the page is generated or on load using JavaScript.

Comment: Also as I mentioned in the question, if I set the width in percent I get a situation where the div inside the td is that percentage of the td, but the td is the width it would need to be to contain the whole text.  If I remove the div, text-overflow has no effect on the tr.

Comment: Correct, and correct. You need to remove the `div`s and specify the width and overflow on the `td`, not the `tr`.

Comment: Sorry, when I said "If I remove the div, text-overflow has no effect on the tr", I meant "If I remove the div, text-overflow has no effect on the td".

Comment: Have you applied a width constraint to the td in addition to the overflow? Can you provide a fiddle of the page that uses this technique rather than the divs?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XVcHV/embedded/result/ - as you can see, the overflow doesn't do anything, and neither does setting the width on the tr.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29504/discussion-between-adrian-and-paul-tomblin)

Comment: Well, I was all happy that it was working, until I went to test it on IE8.  Man I hate IE8!

Comment: Ugh, IE8 is awful, and IE7 is even worse... I'm guessing IE8 doesn't support text-overflow as it's a relatively new property.

Comment: I made the table "table-layout: fixed" which got things nearly working, but not quite.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK a table won't constrain things properly. It's width will break beyond what you specify if you try to have a percentage width TD and DIV.

Can you use just DIVs like this? :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Clipped Text</title>
    <style>
    div#container{width:700px;}
    div.clipped{white-space:nowrap;overflow-x:hidden;width:14%;float:left;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div class="clipped">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
<div class="clipped">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
<div class="clipped">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
<div class="clipped">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
<div class="clipped">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
<div class="clipped">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
<div class="clipped">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems like a poor solution to me; tabular data should be represented in a table.