# Tables don't layout properly in IE7-9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-tables

I have been trying to lay out a table with the following:

- two or three columns that automatically size to fit the content in them
- anywhere from 1 to 4 columns that resize according to the width of the table, and which truncate the text inside them
- one column that contains three buttons and which I want to be *exactly* 220 pixels wide

I got it pretty much working thanks to the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403902/conflicting-requirements-table-columns-expand-to-fill-the-space-available-but).  I set "min-width" on the first two or three columns, and "width" on the last column, and in the middle columns I wrap the text in a div, and then set "max-width" on the td and on the div I set `width: 100%;text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;`.  All that works fine on Chrome and Firefox and Safari and even IE 10.

The problem happens on IE7, 8, and 9.  On all three "browsers", the middle divs don't truncate, they instead push out the width of columns to fit all the text, which blows out the table wider than the page.

I tried putting a `table-layout: fixed;` on the table on IE, but instead of getting what I expected or indeed anything sane at all, instead what I get is that all the columns are given the same width, ignoring the "width: 220px" on the last column's `td`s, and then after everything is laid out the last column expands to 220px, and blows out the table.  If you don't understand what I'm saying, have a look at 
http://jsfiddle.net/ptomblin/rHJk9/
in IE debugger or "Inspect Element" in Chrome or Firefox.  If you look at the "Layout" of a td of last column, and it shows a small width same as all the other columns, even though the contents are 220px wide.

On the live site, putting the "ie8" class on the body is done using conditional `<IF IE8>` code, but jsfiddle doesn't seem to like that.

What I'm looking for is either a way to make the table work the same way on IE7-9 as it does on real browsers (without table-layout:fixed) or some "good enough" work-around that would at least fit on the screen, with or without table-layout:fixed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBCye.jpg has a screen shot showing it on IE9. I've added a red line to show the actual edge of the table. Note how the button bar, which is in a td in that table, extends beyond not just the table, but beyond the actual screen width. (The browser is set to 1024x768, the table is inside a .content div that's 940 pixels wide)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmhgc.jpg is what it looks like in IE9 when you don't have the "table-layout: fixed"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4dCQ.jpg is what it looks like on Chrome without the "table-layout: fixed".  Note how it all fits on the screen and in the table.  That's what I'm aiming for.

Comment: For me it looks identical in IE9 vs. Chrome, and IE9's IE7/8 modes seems to render it more or less correctly, though of course some of the CSS3 styles don't work, and the table is no longer centered on the page. But the rest of your styling works right for me on that fiddle.

Comment: Chrome reports every table cell as being 96px wide, which is plainly wrong, but may give a clue as to why it's doing whatever it is it's doing. In IE9, it looks like the width rules on btn-group are causing the div to be smaller than it should be (shrinking it to td width rather than fitting its contents). The width declaration on the buttons td also appears to be ignored. And the 940 width on the table is also ignored, IE9 and Chrome inspectors say its 1170px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was that caused `table-layout: fixed` to allocate all the columns exactly the same width, no matter what the `width` parameter on the actual column values:  It was happening because the first row on the table had a single column with `colspan="7"`.  I figured it out because on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp) in the description of `table-layout: fixed` they mentioned:

> The browser can begin to display the table once the first row has been received

which made me realize that it was probably only looking at the first row.  I stuck in a dummy first row with empty columns, but with the appropriate classes on each one to give them appropriate widths, and it laid them out much better.  (I also set the font size, height, and line-height, top and bottom margins and padding to 0 for this dummy row so it isn't distracting)